# Persist DateTime to database after modifing it by 30 days

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to fetch DateTime from database

```
$shop = $em->getRepository(BcUserSettings::class)->findOneById($shop_id);
$date = $shop->getSubscriptionExpiresOn();
```

then adding 30 days to it

```
$modify = $date->modify('+30 day');
```

and update it

```
$shop->setSubscriptionExpiresOn($modify);
$em->flush()
```

but my database has still the same DateTime. 
vardumping $modify

```
var_dump($modify);
```

shows

```
object(DateTime)#233 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2018-03-20 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(12) "Asia/Kolkata" }
```

which is also a DateTime object then why doctrine is unable to update it?

Comment: Are you missing an `$em->persist($shop);` before `flush`?

Comment: @JonStirling it's optional, a quote from the docs **You can call $em->persist($product), but it isn't necessary: Doctrine is already "watching" your object for changes.**

Comment: I need to update $shop so i think there is no need to add $em->persist($shop);

Comment: Then you probably need to switch the object. So clone `$date`, modify it, set it, then save.